# Training and testing dataset from different source Neural network

Tags: neural-networks

I am currently building a neural network to classify handwritten characters. I have downloaded the EMNIST dataset to train my neural network. For testing, I also collected samples from students. 
Is the approach to use different sources for the training and testing dataset valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally we would use a dataset that is available publicly. Separate it into training and testing sets. This allows for replication of your results and comparison to other approaches.

You could also try your trained neural net on another data set as you suggest, but I would suggest you start by replicating results on a public dataset to check your implementation is correct.

Comment: It means that is it fine, if i train my neural network on EMNIST datasets, and test on my own sample of handwritten characters ? Because my university lectures said that i should train my neural network from my own samples. @BDN

Comment: Actually, I was suggesting you train and test on the EMNIST dataset. But separate the dataset into training and testing sets first, you can't test on the same images you trained on.  Later you can easily change to your own dataset for training and/or testing.  You may have problems applying items from a different dataset to your trained NN, e.g. the size of the images may be different.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. I totally agree with your suggestion. One more question, if i insist to use the nn that I have trained with emnist database, it means that I should pre process the image first, like resizing, thresholding etc?  Thanks @BDN

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  The input dimension, range, etc. would have to match the data the neural net was trained on.  One other note, if this is university work and your lecturer has specified how you should go about it you should do as they say: they will be the person marking it.  Good luck with your experiment.